# How to fix Postgres on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

When trying to run rails with postgres, i get the following error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

running psql in terminal:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

running

```
ps auxw | grep post
=> will       28386   0.0  0.0  2432804    776 s001  S+    6:27pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn post
```

I installed postres using homebrew, so trying:

```
❯ brew services stop postgresql                                                                                                                                       
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

brew services start postgresql                                                                                                                                
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: I have fixed this by removing the pid file.  rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

Comment: is that just a something-got-corrupted error?

Comment: I don't know enough to say definitively, but I've seen this issue quite often when updating PostgreSQL via homebrew. I think something in the homebrew update script is a bit broken. Not too hard to work around, just annoying.

Comment: @Dave Please open an issue on the [Homebrew repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) to report that. Thanks.

Comment: Anything that avoids regular dev environment meltdown would be aweosome